# Creating layer with geom type wkbGeometryCollection with gdal python?

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, shapely

I am having trouble creating a layer with geom type as geometry collection. Thus I am unable to output to a shapefile. I have attached code below. dstLayer is null. This does not happen if geom type is polygon or multilinestring or any other.

```
spatialReference = osr.SpatialReference()
spatialReference.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS84')
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dstPath = os.path.join("common-border", "border.shp")
dstFile = driver.CreateDataSource(dstPath)
dstLayer = dstFile.CreateLayer("layer", spatialReference, ogr.wkbGeometryCollection)
```

Comment: Geometry type of `Geometry Collection' not supported in shapefiles.

Comment: See this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/71440/65